# How to find and click on the element to login using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I couldn't find and  click the element. HTML is as follows:

```
<button _ngcontent-c2=""> INICIAR SESIÓN </button>
```

I tried using the code:

```
login_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-login/form/div/div/button').click()
```

This is the error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eitan/PycharmProjects/pysel/autopro.py", line 36, in <module>
    login_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-login/form/div/div/button').click()
  File "/home/eitan/PycharmProjects/pysel/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/eitan/PycharmProjects/pysel/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/eitan/PycharmProjects/pysel/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/eitan/PycharmProjects/pysel/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-c2="">...</button> is not clickable at point (624, 648). Other element would receive the click: <img _ngcontent-c2="" src="assets/static/images/login.svg">
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-47-generic x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to `click()` on the element with text as  **INICIAR SESIÓN** you need to induce WebDriverWait for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'INICIAR SESIÓN')]"))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: dosent work : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-c2="">...</button> is not clickable at point (624, 648). Other element would receive the click: <img _ngcontent-c2="" src="assets/static/images/login.svg">
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-47-generic x86_64)

Comment: @ENcy Updated the answer, let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `xpath`

```
login_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'INICIAR')]"
login_element.click()
```

**EDITED**

Seems like webdriver unable to click on the button element.inject java scripts executor to click on the button element or use action class to click.

```
login_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'INICIAR SESIÓN')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",login_element)
```

OR Action class.

```
login_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'INICIAR SESIÓN')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(login_element).click().perform()
```

Use the following imports for action class.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: That thhe one woh work for me:   
login_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'INICIAR SESIÓN')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",login_element)